# Checking a panel unit root test in R done manually

Tags: r, testing, statistics, linear-regression

I have spent much time looking for a special package that could run the Pesaran(2007) unit root test (which assumes cross-sectional dependence unlike most others) and I have found none. So, I decided to do it manually; however, I don't know where I'm going wrong, because my results are very different from Microsoft Excel's results (in which it is done very easily).

My data frame is made up of 22 countries with 506 observations of daily price indices. Following is the model to run using the Pesaran(2007) unit root test:

(i) With an intercept only

[image]

where $\overline{Y}$ is the cross-section average of the observations across countries at each time $t$ and $b$ is the coefficient of interest to us because it will allow us to compute the ADF test statistic and then determine whether the process is stationary or not.

I constructed each of these variables in the following way:

(Delta)Y(t)

```
dif.yt = diff(yt) 
## yt is the object containing all the observations for a specific country 
## (e.g. Australia)
```

Y(t-1)

```
yt.lag.1 = lag(yt, -1)
```

Y(bar)(t-1)

```
ybar.lag.1 = lag(c(rowMeans(x)), -1) 
## x is the object containing my entire data frame
```

(Delta)Y(bar)(t-1)

```
dif.ybar.lag.1 = diff(ybar.lag.1)
```

(Delta)Y(bar)(t-2)

```
dif.ybar.lag.2 = diff(lag(c(rowMeans(x)), -2))
```

(Delta)Y(t-1)

```
dif.yt.lag.1 = diff(yt.lag.1)
```

(Delta)Y(t-2)

```
dif.yt.lag.2 = diff(lag(yt, -2)
```

After constructing each variable individually, I then run the linear regression

```
reg = lm(dif.yt ~ yt.lag.1[-1] + ybar.lag.1[-1] + dif.ybar.lag.1 + 
                  dif.ybar.lag.2 + dif.yt.lag.1 + dif.yt.lag.2)
summary(reg)
```

It is obvious that the explanatory variables in my regression equation differ in length, so I'd like to know whether there is a way in R to make all the variables of equal length (perhaps with a function).

Also, I'd like to know whether the procedure I used was correct and if there are more optimal ways.

Comment: I take that is [Pesaran, M. H. (2007). A simple panel unit root test in the presence of cross section dependence. _Journal of Applied Econometrics 22,_ 365–312.](http://ideas.repec.org/a/jae/japmet/v22y2007i2p265-312.html)

Comment: From ?lm, a warning on using with time series:      Even if the time series attributes are retained, they are not used
     to line up series, so that the time shift of a lagged or
     differenced regressor would be ignored.

Comment: @EricD.Brean That's absolutely right!

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Alright then. I take it that I will always have to manually adjust the length of the series as in "yt.lag.1[-1]" in these cases. But do you have an idea why the coefficients estimates are so different? Thank you.

Comment: Looks to be the case, Saved.  I'm curious as to the outcome.

Comment: Just use `cipstest()` from package `plm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 library(dynlm)

    #object class is a zoo or ts 

  reg =   dynlm(d(yt) ~ (L(yt, 1) + L(ybar,1) + d(L(ybar,1) + ....
     data = ~yourdata, start = .... other args)

summary(reg)
```

More details about the package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynlm/dynlm.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very well actually! I have a few questions though. Does it mean that "d()" is the same as "diff()"? And is "L(xt, 1)" the same as "lag(xt, -1)"? Thank you once again.

Comment: I actually have a table with all the critical values for this test. So, testing hypotheses won't be a problem once I know the formula to calculate the ADF t statistic (coef/se(coef)). Thank you very much!